# jQuery append is breaking browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty new to Javascript/jQuery but I have this code that I am trying to make more robust by removing the hard-coded document.getElementById and replacing them with variables but in doing so I am trying to replace a appendChild with jQuery append and it is breaking the browser.

```
 function Sort(a, b) {
    return (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) ? 1 : -1;
}

var $s = $('#ctl00_FirstColumn_lstAEOTestType');
var options = $('#ctl00_FirstColumn_lstAEOTestType option');
var searchBox = $('#ctl00_FirstColumn_txttypesearch');
$(searchBox).keyup(function () {
    var $HiddenOptions = $('#SelectHidden option');
    $HiddenOptions.each(function (index, value) {
        document.getElementById('ctl00_FirstColumn_lstAEOTestType').appendChild(this);
        //$(options).append(this);  THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO USE
    });
    var search = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    var element = options.filter(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(search);
    }).appendTo(document.getElementById('SelectHidden'));
    $(options).sort(Sort).appendTo(s);
})
$s.scrollTop(0)
```

I have a semi-working example in Jfiddle linked [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kj9p4/1196/).

If you have any suggestions please let me know as I am very new to this.

Comment: define "breaking the browser". It shouldn't be possible to crash the browser using javascript, and your code shouldn't even cause an infinite loop.

Comment: What exactly are we supposed to be suggesting? lol..

Comment: We cannot test your code if you don't provide a fully working example but i think that the first parameter of a keyup event is the element target and you can use that as a reference to the element instead of "this".

Comment: Also please use jQuery if you use jQuery. Change all DOM methods th jQuery to be consistent and is it not supposed to be `!!~`

Comment: Your question  should be how access caller element in javascript event

Comment: `$(options).append(this);` You're appending `option`'s to `options`'s. That's invalid. Shouldn't it be appended to a `select`?

Answer (score 0):

Made some corrections to get you started:

```
var $s = $('#ctl00_FirstColumn_lstAEOTestType');
var options = $('#ctl00_FirstColumn_lstAEOTestType option');
var searchBox = $('#ctl00_FirstColumn_txttypesearch');

$(searchBox).keyup(function () {

    var $HiddenOptions = $('#SelectHidden option');

    $HiddenOptions.each(function (index, value) {
        options.append(this); 
    });

    var search = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    var element = options.filter(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(search);
    }).appendTo('#SelectHidden'); 
    // not sure what 'Sort' is --it'll error out
    //options.sort(Sort).appendTo($s);
})
$s.scrollTop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can refactor your code

```
$(searchBox).keyup(function (elem) {
```

to access the event in a variable and then instead of

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_FirstColumn_lstAEOTestType').appendChild(this);
```

write

```
elem.currentTarget.appendChild(this);
```

this way you don't even need the elemen's id.

A working example

http://jsfiddle.net/devconcept/kj9p4/1197/

*Side note:*

Dom transversal is an expensive operation. Storing the results of a jQuery selector is a good practice but in your case you dont need to perform another jquery lookup because you already have a variable holding the native html element.

If you want to use jQuery methods then write

```
var opt = $(elem.currentTarget);
```